# ⚡️ TypeError: Module name, '@capacitor/splash-screen' does not resolve to a valid URL

Tags: ios, xcode, cross-platform, capacitor

When I create a capacitorjs project and add iOS and then open Xcode and click run it outputs an error in the Xcode output and shows a white screen. the web version of it works fine. I have modified zero code and just run

```
npx cap add ios
npx cap sync
npx cap open ios
```

and then run it from Xcode.
It shows this error in the console

```
⚡️  ------ STARTUP JS ERROR ------

⚡️  TypeError: Module name, '@capacitor/splash-screen' does not resolve to a valid URL.
⚡️  URL: 
⚡️  [error] - {}
⚡️  :0:0

⚡️  See above for help with debugging blank-screen issues
```

I can get the app to display stuff if I remove all references of plugins from the code but that does not really help.

## Update:

I gave up and instead of going through whatever their default framework is just using nextjs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm run build` before `sync`

```
npx cap add ios

npm run build

npx cap sync
npx cap open ios
```

Capacitor's documents don't mention it; I (an app developer) took too long to figure out this. :(